Can we build a measure satisfying this constraint?
Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on some set $\Omega$. Note that $\Sigma$ might not be atomic and could even not contain no atoms at all.
Let $A\in\Sigma$, I want to prove that there exists a measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ that satisfies $\mu(A)=1$ and $\mu(A^c)=0$.
I feel that this is true (under the axiom of choice), I have a sketch of proof below, similar to the extension of linear functions. Is this a known result with a good reference?
Sketch of proof using Zorn's lemma: Consider the collection $E$ couple $(\Sigma',\mu)$ where $\Sigma'$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma$ that contains $A$, and $\mu$ is a measure on $\Sigma'$ satisfying the above condition. Order $E$ by $(\Sigma_1,\mu_1)\leq(\Sigma_2,\mu_2)$ whenever $\Sigma_1\subseteq\Sigma_2$ and $\mu_1(B)=\mu_2(B)$ for all $B\in\Sigma_1$.
If $C$ is a chain in $E$, then $\Sigma_0=\bigcup_{(\Sigma',\mu)}\Sigma'$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma$ that contains $A$ (closed under countable unions is not directly clear but I believe it might hold). Furthermore, for any $B\in\Sigma_0$, there is $(\Sigma',\mu')$ in $C$ such that $B\in\Sigma'$, set $\mu(B)=\mu'(B)$. Then $\mu$ is a measure on $\Sigma_0$ that satisfies the above condition.
By Zorn's Lemma, we have a maximal element $(\Sigma',\mu)$, and if $\Sigma'\neq\Sigma$, we could extend $\Sigma'$ and break maximality.

Without any conditions on the measure or the underlying space, you could just take a point mass at some point in $A$?

Take $x\in A\setminus A^c$ and let $\mu=\delta_x$.

@ThusleGadelankz Well, my algebra could not be atomic (or could even have no atoms), actually I am working on measure theory on a slightly more abstract setting by having measures on Boolean $\sigma$-algebras so there might be no underlying set.

I don't think you need the algebra to be atomic to do this. As long as $A$ is non-empty, pick a point $x \in A$ and define a measure $\mu$ by $\mu(B) = 1$ if $x \in B$ and $\mu(B) = 0$ otherwise.
